# Largest power of a prime dividing $q^m-1$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, divisibility

For positive integers $x$ and $d$ let $v_d(x)$ be the largest power of $d$ dividing $x$.

Let $q>1$, $m$ a natural number, and $l$ a prime dividing $q-1$. Then I want to show that 
$$v_l(q^m-1)=v_l(q-1)+v_l(m)$$ 
with the exception of $l=2$, $v_2(q-1)=1$ and $v_2(m) \geq 1$

The source I found this in refers to only to "van der Waerden" with no further details.

Comment: There was a mathematician by the name of B.L. van der Waerden.  Perhaps it is proved in one of his papers?

Comment: Let $q=1+\ell^rk$ where $\ell\nmid k$, then expand $q^m$ by the binomial theorem and see what it says about $q^m-1$.

Comment: @Gerry: Ugh, I feel silly having done all that work now. That was my first thought, but looking back I had swapped some of the variables in my head and the binomial theorem didn't work out.

Comment: Perhaps you find this treatize helpful: http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf . I'm fiddling in extension with questions like that ... (Page 14/15 seem the most relevant to your question)

Comment: @Gerry. Thanks. From the binomial expansion I can see that $v_l(q^m-1) \geq v_l(q-1)+v_l(m)$. Any advice for $v_l(q^m-1) \leq v_l(q-1)+v_l(m)$? I can't see why for $l=2$ the result would be different.

Comment: Because of that pesky division by 2 in the third term that lets it cancel out the second term to get a surprising extra factor of 2. i.e. every odd number squared is 1 mod 8.

Comment: "van der Waerden" may refer to his classic Algebra textbook. This has been discussed here many times in prior posts. Seach on "lifting exponents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also known as Lifting the Exponent Lemma (LTE).

**Hint:** When $l$ is odd, use binomial theorem to prove that $v_l(q^l-1)=v_l(q-1)+1$ and $v_l(q^m-1)=v_l(q-1)$ for $l \nmid m$. Now induct on $v_l(m)$.

Where does this fail for $l=2$? Note that $v_2(q^2-1)=v_2(q-1)+1$ only holds for $v_2(q-1) \geq 2$.