# $(q+1)\gcd(2m,q+1)$ divides $q^{2m}-1$ where $q$ is a prime power

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer and $q=p^f$ for some prime number $p$ and positive integer $f$. I find the conclusion as the title in the following way:

Let $N$ be the norm of the field extension $GF(q^{2m})/GF(q^2)$, $$G=\{x\in GF(q^{2m})\mid N(x^{q-1})=1\}$$ and $$H=\{x\in GF(q^2)\mid x^{\gcd(2m,q+1)}=1\}.$$ Then $$|H|=\gcd(2m,q+1),$$ and it follows from $G=\{x\in GF(q^{2m})\mid x^{(q^{2m}-1)/(q+1)}=1\}$ that $$|G|=(q^{2m}-1)/(q+1).$$ For any $y\in H$, $y^{q-1}=y^{-2}$ since $y^{q+1}=1$, and so $N(y^{q-1})=y^{(q-1)m}=y^{-2m}=1$. This implies that the group $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$. Hence $\gcd(2m,q+1)=|H|$ divides $|G|=(q^{2m}-1)/(q+1)$, i.e., $(q+1)\gcd(2m,q+1)$ divides $q^{2m}-1$.

Now **the question** is how to prove the conclusion directly via elementary number theory? Or am I missing something above?

**Edit** The question [Largest power of a prime dividing $q^m-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318508/largest-power-of-a-prime-dividing-qm-1?rq=1) is quite related. It seems that using binomial expansion for $q^{2m}$ may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(2m, q+1)$. Write $$q^{2m}-1=(q+1)(q-1)(q^{2(m-1)}+q^{2(m-2)}+\ldots+q^2+1)$$

We have $q \equiv -1 \pmod{d}$ and $d \mid 2m$, so

\begin{align}
\frac{q^{2m}-1}{q+1}& =(q-1)(q^{2(m-1)}+q^{2(m-2)}+\ldots+q^2+1) \\
& \equiv (-1-1)((-1)^{2(m-1)}+(-1)^{2(m-2)}+\ldots+(-1)^2+1) \pmod{d}\\
& \equiv -2(2m) \pmod{d}\\ 
& \equiv 0 \pmod{d}
\end{align}

Thus

$$(q+1)\gcd(2m, q+1) \mid q^{2m}-1$$